# Thinkpad rotation scripts

Tags: thinkpad, display-rotation

I've got a Thinkpad X230 tablet on which I installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04, and I've used Martin Ueding's thinkpad-script PPA to get the screen to rotate.  This has worked for all upgrades.  And then I did a clean install of 18.04, attempted to install thinkpad-scripts and got:

`The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/martin-ueding/stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.`
`N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`
`N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

With a little more digging (UbuntuUpdates) I learned that any repositories that hadn't been actively tweaked for the last two years were cleaned out.  Including the thinkpad-script PPA. Guess it worked *too* well.

So, what can I use instead? Because there's slim pickings in Synaptic and Gnome.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to contact [PPA owner](https://launchpad.net/~martin-ueding) to get scripts released for 18.04 LTS.

But temporarily you can try to install them manually [from PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/martin-ueding/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thinkpad-scripts/):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/martin-ueding/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thinkpad-scripts/thinkpad-scripts_4.11.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./thinkpad-scripts_4.11.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Then check its functionality by yourself.

---

**Note:** I'm unable to install both `thinkpad-rotate` and `thinkpad-scripts` in the same time because of the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 thinkpad-scripts : Breaks: think-rotate (<= 3.3) but 3.2-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
```

so `thinkpad-scripts` replaces `think-rotate`.

Comment: Installed the PPA as you described.  Works like a champ (now I don't have to draw _downhill_.)

Comment: Great! So you can accept my answer :)